# What happens to the non user-id sessions?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm a newbie at GA and I can't seem to find the answer to this question (apologies for any unintended duplicate).
I understood what it means to set up a user-id and what's session unification. What I don't really understand is what happens to the non user-id view when the user-id view is created.
I mean: it stays there, but does it keep collecting data ignoring the user-id or does it ignore the user-id assigned sessions?

I hope it's an understandable question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing happens, the standard view collects sessions normally.
In the user-ID view, on the other hand, only hits that contain the user-ID are collected.